# AngularJS/Bootstrap - Datepicker range filter issues

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using DataTables (http://www.datatables.net/) and Bootstrap datepicker. Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wg3b6y7m/ and the code for the daterange filter:

```
function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    if ($('#min').val() == '' && $('#max').val() == '') {
        return true;
    }

    if ($('#min').val() != '' || $('#max').val() != '') {
        var iMin_temp = $('#min').val();

        if (iMin_temp == '') {
            iMin_temp = '01/01/2000';
        }

        var iMax_temp = $('#max').val();

        if (iMax_temp == '') {
            iMax_temp = '31/12/2999'
        }

        var arr_min = iMin_temp.split("/");
        var arr_max = iMax_temp.split("/");

        // aData[column with dates]
        var arr_date = aData[1].split("/");
        var iMin = new Date(arr_min[2], arr_min[0], arr_min[1], 0, 0, 0, 0)
        var iMax = new Date(arr_max[2], arr_max[0], arr_max[1], 0, 0, 0, 0)
        var iDate = new Date(arr_date[2], arr_date[0], arr_date[1], 0, 0, 0, 0)

        if (iMin == "" && iMax == "") {
            return true;
        } else if (iMin == "" && iDate < iMax) {
            return true;
        } else if (iMin <= iDate && "" == iMax) {
            return true;
        } else if (iMin <= iDate && iDate <= iMax) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

I am having some issues with the datepicker range filter. If I select range 01/01/2015 to 01/28/2015, the rows filter just fine (filtering 2nd column "Date Created"). As soon as I change the "End Date" to 01/29/2015, the first row with a February date appears. Why is it including February dates when my range is still in January?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. Here is the updated code snippet:

```
var iMin = new Date(arr_min[2], parseInt(arr_min[0])-1, arr_min[1], 0, 0, 0, 0)
var iMax = new Date(arr_max[2], parseInt(arr_max[0])-1, arr_max[1], 0, 0, 0, 0)
var iDate = new Date(arr_date[2], parseInt(arr_date[0])-1, arr_date[1], 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The bug is that the month parameter in the `Date` javascript object is `0` indexed, so January is 0, February is 1 and so on. And you are assuming is 1 based, so in reality your limits are in February 29th.

I totally recommend you use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for all your javascript date/time needs.

After reading your javascript, it seems to me that you come from PHP righ? *High five*. This is out of topic but here are a few ideas on your javascript code.

```
function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    // Save variables instead of calling the method multiple times
    var min = $('#min').val();
    var max = $('#max').val();

    // Prefer exact comparison over "lax" comparison,
    // so === instead of ==, this is because javascript has a very
    // weird comparison table where 0 == false, sometimes you 
    // don't want to compare a number to boolean, sometimes you might
    // but that's error prone, so it's safer to use ===
    if (min === '' && max === '') {
        return true;
    }

    // Instead of nesting, do a reverse check and exit, makes it easier to follow
    // Hey... you already done it above, no need to repeat the check.
    // if (min === '' && max === '') { 
    //   return false;
    // }

    // No need to redeclare
    // var iMin_temp = min;
    // var iMax_temp = max;

    if (min === '') {
        min = '01/01/2000';
    }

    if (max === '') {
        max = '31/12/2999';
    }

    var arr_min = iMin_temp.split("/");
    var arr_max = iMax_temp.split("/");

    // aData[column with dates]
    var arr_date = aData[1].split("/");
    var iMin = new Date(arr_min[2], arr_min[0], arr_min[1], 0, 0, 0, 0);
    var iMax = new Date(arr_max[2], arr_max[0], arr_max[1], 0, 0, 0, 0);
    var iDate = new Date(arr_date[2], arr_date[0], arr_date[1], 0, 0, 0, 0);

    // If you are parsing the dates above, they can't be empty strings, 
    // so just feel free to compare them directly as dates.
    // if (iMin == "" && iMax == "") {
    //     return true;
    // } else if (iMin == "" && iDate < iMax) {
    //     return true;
    // } else if (iMin <= iDate && "" == iMax) {
    //     return true;
    // } else if (iMin <= iDate && iDate <= iMax) {
    //     return true;
    // }
    // return false;
    return iMin <= iDate && iDate <= iMax;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I don't think I've worked with PHP, I'm just using the DateRange javascript from DataTables. Could you please clarify the `Date` javascript object indexed as 0? I'm still not sure why 1/29/15 allows February dates to show up.

Comment: If you execute this in the browser console `new Date(2015, 01, 29)` you'll see that the date parsed is actually February 29th, the thing is that the table is not showing you all the filtered results, only the first page.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Do you know how would I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: Sorry, DataTables is not my forte :)